# SQL Query duplicates sum for each join

Tags: sql-server, mysql, sum

I'm trying to do this table which will give me a date, and then sum up sales from a separate table, but the sales values get multiplied 14 times for some reason. Will this need a temp table, or am I missing something obvious in my join?

```
    -- Set the base dates
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '01-Jun-2022 00:00:00'
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = '01-Jul-2022 00:00:00'
DECLARE @PeriodID VARCHAR(50) = '10'
DECLARE @MarketID VARCHAR(50) = 'GB'


    SELECT [c].[CustomerID]  'Customer ID'
        ,[o].[OrderID]
        , [c].[FirstName]
        , [c].[LastName]
        , [c].[Field3]
        , FORMAT([c].[Date1], 'dd/MM/yyyy') 'Join Date'
        , FORMAT(MAX([bep1].[EndDate]), 'dd/MM/yyyy') 'BEP1 Date'
        , FORMAT(MAX([bep2].[EndDate]), 'dd/MM/yyyy') 'BEP2 Date'
        , FORMAT(MAX([bep3].[EndDate]), 'dd/MM/yyyy') 'BEP3 Date'
        , FORMAT(MAX([bep4].[EndDate]), 'dd/MM/yyyy') 'BEP4 Date'

        , SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH , [c].[Date1], EOMONTH([o].[OrderDate])) = 0 THEN [od].[CommissionableVolume] ELSE 0 END ) AS 'Mth1 Sales'
        , SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH , [c].[Date1], EOMONTH([o].[OrderDate])) = 1 THEN [od].[CommissionableVolume] ELSE 0 END ) AS 'Mth2 Sales'
        , SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH , [c].[Date1], EOMONTH([o].[OrderDate])) = 2 THEN [od].[CommissionableVolume] ELSE 0 END ) AS 'Mth3 Sales'
        , SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH , [c].[Date1], EOMONTH([o].[OrderDate])) = 3 THEN [od].[CommissionableVolume] ELSE 0 END ) AS 'Mth4 Sales'
        , SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH , [c].[Date1], EOMONTH([o].[OrderDate])) = 4 THEN [od].[CommissionableVolume] ELSE 0 END ) AS 'Mth5 Sales'
        , SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH , [c].[Date1], EOMONTH([o].[OrderDate])) = 5 THEN [od].[CommissionableVolume] ELSE 0 END ) AS 'Mth6 Sales'
        , SUM([od].[CommissionableVolume]) AS 'Sales Volume'
    
    FROM [dbo].[Customers] [c]
        LEFT JOIN [dbo].[PeriodVolumes] [pv] ON [c].[CustomerID] = [pv].[CustomerID] AND [pv].[PeriodTypeID] = 20
        LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Periods] [bep1] ON [bep1].[PeriodID] = [pv].[Volume43] AND [bep1].[PeriodTypeID] = 20 AND [pv].[Volume43] > 0
        LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Periods] [bep2] ON [bep2].[PeriodID] = [pv].[Volume44] AND [bep2].[PeriodTypeID] = 20 AND [pv].[Volume44] > 0
        LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Periods] [bep3] ON [bep3].[PeriodID] = [pv].[Volume45] AND [bep3].[PeriodTypeID] = 20 AND [pv].[Volume45] > 0
        LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Periods] [bep4] ON [bep4].[PeriodID] = [pv].[Volume46] AND [bep4].[PeriodTypeID] = 20 AND [pv].[Volume46] > 0

        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Orders] [o] ON REPLACE(REPLACE([o].[Other11],CHAR(9),''),' ','') = [c].[CustomerID] 
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[OrderDetails] [od] ON [od].[OrderID] = [o].[OrderID]

    WHERE (1=1)
        
        AND ([c].[Field3] = @MarketId OR  @MarketId = 'All')
        AND [c].[Date1] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate

        AND [c].[CustomerID] = '3009737'
            
    GROUP BY [c].[CustomerID]
    ,[o].[OrderID]
        , [c].[FirstName]
        , [c].[LastName]
        , [c].[Field3]
        , FORMAT([c].[Date1], 'dd/MM/yyyy')
    
    ORDER BY FORMAT([c].[Date1], 'dd/MM/yyyy') ASC
    ,[c].[CustomerID]  ASC
```

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Comment: Your `JOIN`s and / or `GROUP BY` clause are incorrect, causing the increased number of rows. Without seeing the Table definitions, and example data for each, it's hard to tell exactly what part. Comment out the `GROUP BY`, all `JOIN`s and the `SELECT` list. Then only add in the key field of each Table as you go, and uncomment a single `JOIN` one by one until you start to see the data duplicated unexpectedly. Then you've found your problem. If the raw data appears correct after adding back all the `JOIN`s, then you have just an incorrect `GROUP BY` clause and need to look closer at it.

Comment: Your code is MS SQL-specific, and it will fail in MySQL. Check your DBMS carefully.

Comment: To avoid JOIN multiplying you must aggregate single table (or minimal tableset) in CTE/subquery then join another tables.

Answer (score 2):

One rule to keep in mind:  `JOINs` are done before aggregation.  That is,...

1. All `JOINing` is performed; a temporary table is created.  If some of the JOINs represent 1:many relationships, the number of rows may be larger than any of the original tables.
2. Rows that don't match the `WHERE` are tossed.
3. Now the `GROUP BY` is applied.  The `SUM()` is applied to the rows in that temp table.  Because of any 1:many relationships, some number may show up multiple times, hence inflating the "sum".

Usually, the solution is to do aggregations (and `GROUP BYs`) on the table as a separate step.  *Then* `JOIN` to the rest.

```
SELECT ..., sumb, ...
    FROM ( SELECT a, SUM(b) sumb FROM x GROUP BY a ) AS y
    JOIN ... ON y.a = ...
```